# MOUSEBUTTON events in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have made a sort of cookie clicker like game in pygame, however when I click the mouse once loads of points are added to the score. I assume this is because of the game loop, however I would like to know how to make this stop, and make it add 1 to the score for every click, no matter how long the mouse button is held down.

Comment: How are you detecting mouse clicks? You should probably use `pygame.event.get()` rather than [pygame.mouse.get_pressed](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed).

Comment: You should show your code. If it is too long then create a small representative example.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that only increments the score on mouse button down events:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([320,240])
sys_font = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 18)

pygame.display.set_caption("Clicker")
clicks = 0  # initialise the score counter
done = False
while not done:
    #Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            clicks += 1

    #Graphics
    screen.fill(pygame.color.Color("white"))
    score_txt = sys_font.render(f"Clicks: {clicks}", True, pygame.color.Color("blue"))
    screen.blit(score_txt, (20, 220))
    #Frame Change
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

[image: Example Clicker GUI]

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 variables like `is_mouse_clicked` and `was_mouse_clicked_previously`.

- In the initialization of the game (even before the first loop), assign `False` to both of them.
- At the beginning of the game loop assign value of `is_mouse_clicked` to `was_mouse_clicked_previously`
- Then, load the information whether the mouse button is being pressed to `is_mouse_clicked` variable
- Then, add the point if the values of `is_mouse_clicked` and `was_mouse_clicked_previously` differ.

  - Option 1: Adding points inside `if is_mouse_clicked and not was_mouse_clicked_previously:` will increase the score right away (the moment you start pressing the button)
  - Option 2: Adding points inside `if not is_mouse_clicked and was_mouse_clicked_previously:` will increase the score a bit later (the moment you release the button)